# The limit of the square root of two times the square root of two times.....

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, nested-radicals

i'd like to know how to prove that following sequence

$$\sqrt{2\sqrt2},\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}},\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}}},...$$

Is convergent, and that it's limit equals two.

In other words, that
$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2...}}}=2$$

I imagine it's supposed to be simple and straightfoward, but i cant figure it out. I would be grateful for any help you could give me.

Comment: I misread the question, $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}$ is not the same as $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}$. It's a duplicate of "[How I can prove that the sequence $\sqrt{2} , \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}$ converges to 2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200416/856)" instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sequence could be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{cases}
a_0=\sqrt{2}\\
a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}
\end{cases}
$$

By induction, you can easily prove that:

$$
a_n=2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}}=2^{(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}, n\geq 1
$$

The sum in the power converges, hence the sequence converges and the limit is $2$

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did something similar the first time i tried this, the problem is that i find

$
a_n=2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}}=2^{\sum{(\frac{1}{2^n})}}
$

Where i know that the series $\sum{(\frac{1}{2^n})}$ converges to 2. How do i find that 

${\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}}={(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}, n\geq 1
$? What am i missing?

Comment: @BrM Careful: where you know the series **converges to** $\;1\;$ ...observe that geometric series begins with $\;n=1\;$ ...

Comment: ooooooh.....  * *facepalm* *

Answer (score 8):

Here's a non-rigorous way to find the answer.  Call the final result $x$.  Then $x^2 = 2 \cdot x$, and you can solve for $x$.  This method can give the wrong answer for similar-looking problems: the iteration can converge to different values depending on the starting point, or it may not converge at all.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that $0$ is also a solution to this equation, and so when checking the sequence converges, you'd also need to check it converges to the right root.

Comment: B. Mehta indeed, and without specifying the meaning of the expression $\sqrt{2 \cdot \sqrt{2 \cdot \sqrt{2 \cdot \dots}}}$ as a limit of certain finite expressions, it's arguably equally valid to say that it equals $0$.

Comment: This answer and Don Antonio 's answer form a complete solution

Comment: I think the method is rigorous, right? You just have to remember it's a one-way implication... or is it actually not rigorous?

Answer (score 7):

An idea: define

$$x_1:=\sqrt2\;,\;\;x_2=\sqrt{2x_1}\,,\ldots,x_n:=\sqrt{2x_{n-1}}$$

Show that $\;\{x_n\}\;$ is (1) bounded and (2) monotone ascending, and thus it has a limit. Now use arithmetic of limits.