# $X_1 = 1, X_{n+1} = \sqrt{2X_n}$ and $n ≥ 1$ Show that $X_n$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $X_n \,\,(n∈N)$ be a sequence defined by
>   $X_1 = 1, X_{n+1} = \sqrt{2X_n}$ and $n ≥ 1$.
>   Show that $X_n$ is convergent.

So I guess ${X_n}$ goes to a number like $$\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\dots}}}}}.$$
But i'm not even sure if this makes $X_n$ convergent. And therefore can't prove it.

First time I'm asking a question here. Sorry if i did something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Can you show $X_n$ is strictly monotonically [increasing and bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) by $2$?

Comment: is it $\sqrt2\,x_n$ or $\sqrt{2x_n}$?

Comment: I think it's the latter

Comment: In that case it obviously converges, because it is monotonic increasing and bounded above by 2.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200416/42969

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. I will be more careful and use MathJax in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step I:**

Use induction to show that each term is less than $2$. Inductive Step is $$X_k<2\implies X_{k+1}=\sqrt{2X_k}<\sqrt{2\times 2}=2$$

**Step II:**

Use induction to show that given sequence is increasing. Inductive Step is
$$X_{k}>X_{k-1}\implies\sqrt{2X_k}>\sqrt{2X_{k-1}}\implies X_{k+1}>X_k$$

Since it is a monotonic bounded sequence, hence convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $x_n\to L$ then $\sqrt{2x_n}\to\sqrt{2l}$, so we must have $L=\sqrt{2L}$, or $L=2$.

So showing that $x_n$ converges is the same as showing that $x_n\to2$. Which motivates the following: It follows by induction that $x_n<2$. Hence $x_{n+1}^2=2x_n>x_n^2$. So the sequence is monotone and bounded, hence convergent.

Answer (score 0):

To show that it's convergent, we can show that's it's monotone increasing and bounded above (by $2$). To show that it's monotone increasing, we need to show that $X_n < X_{n+1} $ for $n\geq 1$. We can do so by induction. When $n=1, 1=X_n < X_{n+1}=\sqrt{2},$ so the base case holds. Assume the result holds for some $k\in\mathbb{N}, k < n$. Then $X_k < X_{k+1}$. Since $X_{k+2} =\sqrt{2X_{k+1}}>\sqrt{2X_k}$ by hypothesis, the result holds by induction.

Now, to show that it's bounded above by $2$, we see that the base case holds as $X_1 = 1 <2$. Assume $X_k < 2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}, k < n$. Then $X_{k+1} =\sqrt{2X_k} < \sqrt{2\cdot 2} = 2$, so the result holds by induction.

Hence by MCT the sequence converges.